# Convert ctypes object to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I’m trying to write a ctypes structure so that it can be easily converted into a numpy array and used for assignments. Here is a simple example that shows the issue:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_double
import numpy as np

class Vec3d:
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    def __array__(self, dtype):
        return np.array([self.x, self.y, self.z])

class Vec3dS(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_double), ("y", c_double), ("z", c_double)]
    def __array__(self, dtype):
        return np.array([self.x, self.y, self.z])

v = Vec3d()
vs = Vec3dS(1,2,3)
n = np.zeros((2,3))
n[0] = v
n[1] = vs
```

The first assignment `n[0]=v` works but not the second one `n[1]=vs`. Numpy seems to be able to convert `v` to an numpy array but the assignment ultimately fails because the array has the wrong dtype:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]) to dtype('float64').
```

It’s the same dtype as if I were using

```
np.array(vs)
```

Why does implementing `__array__` (I also tried `__array_interface__`) not work when using a `ctypes.Structure`? How do I have to modify the `Vec3dS` class to give numpy a hint on how to convert it to a numpy array with the right dtype and values?

**Edit**: I suspect `ctypes.Structure` implements PEP 3118 which takes precedence over `__array__`. Is it possible to overwrite this from the python side?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) seems to work well enough.

```py
v = Vec3d(1,2,3)
l = [1,2,3]
n = np.zeros((2,3))

n[0] = l
n[1] = np.frombuffer(v)

assert (n[0] == n[1]).all()
```

Comment: Yes but that is not the answer I’m looking for. I don’t want to change the way the assignment is done. I’m looking for a way to tell numpy how to convert this object to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `np.zeros(2, dtype=Vec3dS)` instead of `np.zeros((2,3))` then you don't need to use `__array__` at all on the ctypes structure:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, c_double
import numpy as np

class Vec3d:
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    def __array__(self, dtype):
        return np.array(
            (self.x, self.y, self.z),
            dtype=[('x', np.double), ('y', np.double), ('z', np.double)])

class Vec3dS(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_double), ("y", c_double), ("z", c_double)]

v = Vec3d()
vs = Vec3dS(1,2,3)
n = np.zeros(2, dtype=Vec3dS)
# note: since the array is 1d, we need `...` to prevent decay to scalars, which
# don't behave well with `__array__`
n[0, ...] = v
n[1, ...] = vs
```